# ¿Como puedo meter en variables las distintas filas de un ExecuteReader?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo una clase publica con variables estaticas, y la consulta me devuelve 2 filas, pero al recorrerse se me sobreescriben las variables y solo me muestra el ultimo recorrido, como guardo todas la información para mostrar todas las filas en una lista.

```
 public void LlenarReporte(string nombre)
    {
        using (var conexionN = new SqlConnection(conexionBD.ConexionBasesD(nombre)))
        {
            conexionN.Open();
            using (var comando = new SqlCommand())
            {
                comando.Connection = conexionN;
                comando.CommandText = "sp_MostrarComprobanteFactura";
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idfactura", IdFactura);
                comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                 
                
                SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {                       
                    while (reader.Read())                        
                    {
                        DatosFactura.IdFactura = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        DatosFactura.NombreCliente = reader.GetString(1);
                        DatosFactura.NumDoc_Cliente = reader.GetString(2);
                        DatosFactura.SerieFactura = reader.GetString(3);
                        DatosFactura.SecuencialFactura = reader.GetString(4);
                        DatosFactura.MetodoPago = reader.GetString(5);
                        DatosFactura.FechaFactura = reader.GetDateTime(6);
                        DatosFactura.ReferProd = reader.GetString(7);
                        DatosFactura.NombreProd = reader.GetString(8);
                        DatosFactura.Cantidad = reader.GetInt32(9);
                        DatosFactura.PrecioUnitario = reader.GetDecimal(10);
                        DatosFactura.DescuentoProducto = reader.GetDecimal(11);
                        DatosFactura.DetalleVentaTotal = reader.GetDecimal(12);
                        DatosFactura.SubTotal = reader.GetDecimal(13);                            
                        DatosFactura.Descuento = reader.GetDecimal(18);                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Al guardar los datos en las variables, llenaba una lista que se encontraba en otra clase de esta manera:

```
 class ClaseLlenarDatosFact
{
    DModeloFactura fact = new DModeloFactura();

    private List<ClaseFacturaL> lista_ClaseFactura;       

    public ClaseLlenarDatosFact(int id, string nombre)
    {
        lista_ClaseFactura = new List<ClaseFacturaL>();

        fact.ReporteFactura(id, nombre);

        int idF = DatosFactura.IdFactura;
        string nombreC = DatosFactura.NombreCliente;
        string documento = DatosFactura.NumDoc_Cliente;
        string serie = DatosFactura.SerieFactura;
        string secuencial = DatosFactura.SecuencialFactura;
        string pago = DatosFactura.MetodoPago;
        DateTime fecha = DatosFactura.FechaFactura;
        string codigo = DatosFactura.ReferProd;
        string producto = DatosFactura.NombreProd;
        int cantidad = DatosFactura.Cantidad;
        decimal preciou = DatosFactura.PrecioUnitario;
        decimal descuentoprod = DatosFactura.DescuentoProducto;


        lista_ClaseFactura.Add(new ClaseFacturaL(idF, nombreC, documento, serie, secuencial, pago,
                fecha, codigo, producto, cantidad, preciou, descuentoprod));
    }

    public List<ClaseFacturaL> ObtenerLista()
    {
        return lista_ClaseFactura;
    }
}}
```

Pero solo me tomaba la ultima fila.

Mi clase `ClaseFacturaL` tiene los metodos `get` y `set` de las variable

```
get { return variable; }
set { variable = value; }
```

El procedimiento almacenado me devuelve todas las filas con la unión de 2 tablas. Lo que quiero es guardar estos datos en una variable y llenar una lista, para hacer un report viewer, lo habia hecho de una manera pero solo me tomaba la ultima fila, y es porque me sobreescribe el `while` las `variables`. ¿Como guardo todas mis filaspara crear el Objeto en el report viewer?

Answer (score 0):

No se muy bien que querías lograr usando variables estáticas, pero el valor se va a sobrescribir en cada iteración del while, necesitas guardar los datos en una lista representada por la clase. Las propiedades no deben ser estáticas.

```cs
List<DatosFactura> datos = new List<>();
while (reader.Read())                        
{
    DatosFactura df = new DatosFactura();
    DatosFactura.IdFactura = reader.GetInt32(0);
    DatosFactura.NombreCliente = reader.GetString(1);
    DatosFactura.NumDoc_Cliente = reader.GetString(2);
    DatosFactura.SerieFactura = reader.GetString(3);
    DatosFactura.SecuencialFactura = reader.GetString(4);
    DatosFactura.MetodoPago = reader.GetString(5);
    DatosFactura.FechaFactura = reader.GetDateTime(6);
    DatosFactura.ReferProd = reader.GetString(7);
    DatosFactura.NombreProd = reader.GetString(8);
    DatosFactura.Cantidad = reader.GetInt32(9);
    DatosFactura.PrecioUnitario = reader.GetDecimal(10);
    DatosFactura.DescuentoProducto = reader.GetDecimal(11);
    DatosFactura.DetalleVentaTotal = reader.GetDecimal(12);
    DatosFactura.SubTotal = reader.GetDecimal(13);                            
    DatosFactura.Descuento = reader.GetDecimal(18);

    datos.Add(df);
}
```